# nupenGl and visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using Visual C++ 2015. I downloaded NupenGl and extracted and when creating new projects I set the additional include libraries and additional linker input.

When I run the program I get error:

```
glutInit(& amp; argc, argv); // amp is undeclared identifier
```

so what's missing? thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code. Afaik, `glutInit` has only two parameters. And for sure there is no `;` inside the parenthesis of a function call.

Comment: why not helping instead of voting down?

Comment: @BDL it's not my code: glutinit(&amp, argc, argv) but in header file

Comment: In which headerfile? In my `glut.h` file, there is no such line of code...

Comment: glut.h includes freeglut_std.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have broken sources. Correct code should be: `glutInit(&argc, argv);`.

It seems that `&` was replaced by `&amp;` converting the text to URL representation. If you downloaded that code - try another method of downloading without breaking files.

Comment: thank you for your help!